# Can ADB Handle Multiple Connections?

Tags: adb

I am trying to script ADB and I was wandering if it can handle multiple installs at the same time in different threads. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Yes, it is. You can specify the device ID at the command prompt. Just invoke `adb` without any parameters to see its full syntax.

Comment: Even on the same device?

Comment: Nope, not that I know of. You should update your question to make clear what you target at. To me it looked like you meant "different/multiple devices", sorry.